# Create Drill down on Stacked Chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, drilldown, powerbi-desktop

I have some sample data as shown:

```
     Site   Ready   Not Ready   Training    Break    Other
      A     78%        22%          0%        5%      16%
      B      57%       43%          0%        6%      37%
      C      56%       44%          0%        1%      43%
      D     94%        6%           0%        0%      6%
```

Where 'Site': Call Center Site,
Ready: % of time agents are in a ready state

Not Ready: % of time agents are in a not ready state (further broken down by 'Training', 'Break' and 'Other' states)

I want to show a stacked graph that shows a proportion of time in Ready vs Not Ready State; and when drilled down on Not Ready, it should show proportions of Training, Break and Other states. The Excel equivalent of this would be a pie of a pie chart, but I am stuck when I try to do this in PowerBI. Any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll want to reshape your data to the following:

```
Site  State      Substate  Value
--------------------------------
A     Ready      Ready     0.78
A     Not Ready  Training  0.00
A     Not Ready  Break     0.05
A     Not Ready  Other     0.16 
B     Ready      Ready     0.57
B     Not Ready  Training  0.00
B     Not Ready  Break     0.06
B     Not Ready  Other     0.37 
C     Ready      Ready     0.56
C     Not Ready  Training  0.00
C     Not Ready  Break     0.01
C     Not Ready  Other     0.43 
D     Ready      Ready     0.94
D     Not Ready  Training  0.00
D     Not Ready  Break     0.00
D     Not Ready  Other     0.06
```

To do this, delete the `Not Ready` column and unpivot the remaining columns except `Site` to create the `Substate` column. Then create the `State` column as a custom column:

`if [State] = "Ready" then "Ready" else "Not Ready"`

(Note: You could just as easily create this with a DAX calculated column instead.)

---

Once your data is reshaped, it's much easier to work with. Just put `State` and `Substate` in the Legend box of a pie chart and the `Value` in the Values box.

[image: Top Level]

From there you can either drill down on `Not Ready` or pass to the `Substate` level of the hierarchy:

[image: Drill Down]
[image: Next Level]

---

If you're interested, there is also a [Drill-down donut chart](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380858) that is pretty nifty for this sort of thing.